# Paramiko : Throwing error when trying to execute python on remote server

Tags: python, paramiko

I have a program to execute python on a remote server using Paramiko . So it is just that the script to call python is located in one remote server and the script caling is located on another  .

So i thought of using Paramiko . But it is throwing me error . tried to correct error using different methods obtained from stack but in vain . Can anyone kindy help .

```
import paramiko 
import sys
import os 


host = "powe76nk.dfrlpw.com"
port = 8015
username = "tre@dfrlpw"
password = "abcd"

command = "D:\***\FlaskTest\Callfunction.py"

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(host, port, username, password)


stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(command)
lines = stdout.readlines()
print(lines)
```

and it is throwing me error

```
D:\Programs\FlaskAPICallTest\CallingPythonFile>python testingserver.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testingserver.py", line 15, in <module>
    ssh.connect(host, port, username, password)
  File "C:\Users\fmxdev\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages
\paramiko\client.py", line 368, in connect
    raise NoValidConnectionsError(errors)
paramiko.ssh_exception.NoValidConnectionsError: [Errno None] Unable to connect t
o port 8015 on *****
```

was not able to solve this issue and is checking this for the last 2 days . Is there any alternate for this

Answer (score 0):

Your username should be tre and not tre@dfrlpw.

Also can you manually ssh into the server using ssh command or putty?

Comment: May i know how to do that , because when i did it shows ssh is not  recognized

Comment: Use puTTy software if you are in windows

Comment: Okay i will check that now

Comment: The Paramiko code cannot even connect to the server, so it cannot be a username issue. Though testing this first with any commandline/GUI SSH client running on the same machine as the Python code is indeed the right thing to do (and OP should have done than even before posting the question).